# ignite C++: serialization class not found in cache store

Tags: c++, ignite

I am trying to use cache store for persistance. I have implemented serialization of user defined object using binarytype template. But still when configuring cassandra cache store in spring xml. Im getting errors like deserializer not found or class id not found expections. I had even tried the binary configurations available in docs, but it didn't work. Can someone help in resolving the issue.

ERROR CODE:

```
> [21:46:12,349][SEVERE][main][GridDhtAtomicCache] <cachekey> Unexpected
> exception during cache update class
> org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed resolve class
> for ID: -1516436005   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:699)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1491)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1450)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:637)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:142)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectContext.java:272)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:160)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:147)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1742)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.put(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:566)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerUpdate(GridCacheMapEntry.java:2507)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateSingle(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2479)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1881)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1721)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.mapSingle(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:263)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.map(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:494)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.mapOnTopology(GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFuture.java:436)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.map(GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateFuture.java:208)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.update0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1236)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.put0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:671)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.put(GridCacheAdapter.java:2276)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.put(GridCacheAdapter.java:2253)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.put(IgniteCacheProxy.java:1375)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.cache.PlatformCache.processInStreamOutLong(PlatformCache.java:409)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformTargetProxyImpl.inStreamOutLong(PlatformTargetProxyImpl.java:61)
> Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Class
> definition was not found at marshaller cache and local file.
> [id=-1516436005,
> file=/apache-ignite-fabric-1.9.0-bin/work/marshaller/-1516436005.classname]
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.className(MarshallerContextImpl.java:218)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextAdapter.getClass(MarshallerContextAdapter.java:174)
>   at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:683)
```

Comment: What the exception exactly?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the errors.

Comment: Have you defined the same class in Java too?

Comment: This is an Ignite c++ server. And I have not defined any Java class for this. If so can you let me know where to create the equivalent java class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to set `storeKeepBinary` on `CacheConfiguration`, if you only have difinition of your class in C++. Also, you may want to take a look at [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-4205), as there are some issues with Cassandra store. It seems to be in "Patch available" state, so seems like fix is going to be in master soon.

Comment: Using <property name="storeKeepBinary" value="true"/> it worked. Thank you so much.